# SQL Select default value in a query from a table

Tags: sql

I have a query which I want to have a default value from a table (you could call it a vlookup in excel). My query looks like this:

```
select stamdata_sd.id_sd AS id_sd, stamdata_sd.Type_sd
AS Type_sd from stamdata_sd;
```

I want the `Type_sd` field in the query to be a default value from a table called `type_ty`. Something like this:

```
select stamdata_sd.id_sd AS id_sd, stamdata_sd.Type_sd default(selected
from a table called type_ty, where the pk id_ty is the higest)
AS Type_sd from stamdata_sd;
```

So, when i make a new record in the query, the field `Type_sd` is auto filled with the newest instance in the `type_ty` table.

How am I able to write such a query?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to store the right value in the table stamdata_sd in the first place?

Comment: to inscrease the workflow when typing in new data. then the user dont have to type the value, and the value changes time to time, so i can not just make it a default value.

Comment: ups... that was in fact wrong...

Comment: So you designed a table to always contain incorrect data, to have a nullable column that's supposed to be `NOT NULL`, and to increase complexity and execution time, because you want users to not have to type *one value* once a day or once a week? I'd be surprised if the contributors to SO couldn't come up with a dozen different ways to fix that. I *would* be surprised if your solution didn't turn out to be the worst possible way to do it. Reconsider this design.

Comment: Its not a good design, you are right. But it could be nice if the default value could change, based on data in a table (the newest instans), but i dont think it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a really bad design. Your table will always have incorrect data in it. And it will always have some nulls in a column that should probably be `NOT NULL`.

If I were you, I'd try writing a BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers to make sure the right data always goes into the base table. You can SELECT the current value from your type_ty table.

The use of a BEFORE INSERT trigger is obvious. But you also want to make sure good data goes into that column should a user try to set it to NULL or to an empty string. So you need a BEFORE UPDATE trigger, too.

There are also good ways to handle this in client code, after first fixing the data and constraints in the base table. Client code can require a value once a session, which it can use as the current value, or it can remember the last value used and insert it into the user interface (where it might be overtyped with a different value). You could store the current value in a cookie. Lots of ways.

Comment: I am not using the design i can se that now. The last suggestion sound like a good solution, i will se if i can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ANSI-Standard [`COALESCE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#COALESCE) function. This function will test its arguments in order, and return the first of them that is not `null`.

It would be something in this shape:

```
select 
  stamdata_sd.id_sd AS id_sd, 
  COALESCE(stamdata_sd.Type_sd, 
    (select max(t.name_of_colum) from type_ty t) ) AS Type_sd 
from stamdata_sd
```

Comment: `TOP N` is non-Standard (hint: `MAX`).

Comment: @onedaywhen thank you for the tip. I do not know what I was thinkin about :)

Comment: good answer, thanks, but it will not accept the `select max(t.name_of_colum) from type_ty t` even if its a integer. I am trying this: `select 
  stamdata_sd.id_sd AS id_sd, 
  COALESCE(stamdata_sd.Type_sd, 
    select max(lutbunke.id) from lutbunke) AS Type_sd 
from stamdata_sd` i get error number 1064, which isnt helping me at all.

Comment: @Thomas have you tried putting `select max(lutbunke.id) from lutbunke` inside parenthesis? I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

> So, when i make a new record in the query, the field type_sd is auto
>   filled with the newest instans in the type_ty table.

It seems you want the INSERT statement to grab a particular value from some other table:

```
               insert into ZOO(animal)
               values
               ( {the most recently added animal in the ANIMALS table} )
```

One way to grab the most recently added row in a table is to use a TIMESTAMP column, which is updated with the value corresponding to "now" when the row is inserted:

```
                create table ANIMALS(id integer primary key autoincrement, 
                      animal text, creationdate timestamp)
```

N.B. How databases handle timestamps varies, so treat the above as pseudo-code.

```
                insert into ANIMALS(animal) values('lion')
```

would result in something like this:

```
                 1,   lion,   2011-09-23 08:00:05.123
```

You can get the most recently added animal like this (assuming that no two records are created at exactly the same millisecond):

```
                 select animal from ANIMALS
                 where creationdate = (select max(creationdate) from ANIMALS)
```

Thus:

```
               insert into ZOO(animal)
               select animal from ANIMALS 
               where creationdate = (select max(creationdate) from ANIMALS)
```